# Why does baking the armature (as an object) stop the bones from moving?

Tags: animation, armature, bones, constraints, baking

I want to get rid of the Follow Path Constraint without while keeping the animation of the armature as a whole or as an object. In Object Mode, I baked it by going to **Object menu** > **Animation** > **Bake Action**

[image]

It works and now I can delete the Bezier Curve without loosing the animation of the armature. BUT the animation of each individual bone stops! How can I solve this?

**Example**: Try to bake the armature in the attached file.
[Download Blend File](https://blenderartists.org/uploads/short-url/ki4cRvQBuayIPlbsBYjiklnMPEC.blend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to bake the bones actions, you have to be in pose mode. From there you can make a bake of visual keying of bones AND object transforms (just shift select both pose and object in the bake tab).

[image]

Comment: My great josh :D Thank you so much.. That was quick and useful :)